# Что я мог нажать?) (Мой вопрос о java и IDE Intellij-Idea)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Что такого я мог нажать, изучая программу IntellijIdea и как это исправить? В общем, суть вопроса такова, что после этого сразу же, после перевода курсора кликом мыши в другое место, удаляется строчка в пустом файле main.java. Приложение абсолютно в себе ничего не содержит, как можете видеть. Я ещё новичок в JAVA, отрабатываю азы)
До этого кликал в настройках верхнего меню какие то пункты, в подменю code и ещё где-то))

```
package com.company
import java.util.scanner; - строчка сразу же удаляется при переходе курсора по клику мыши в другое место.
 public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Имя класса и файла должно быть с большой буквы, то есть `public class Main`

Comment: Сбросил настройки, помогло, просто интересно, что за пункт в меню такой был. На будущее, чтобы предусмотрительнее быть. Насчёт класса - невнимателен был, благодарю за замечание, в программе, причём, с большой как надо писал) Но за комментарии всё равно спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Сбрось настройки на "заводские" и все дела!